# Are there Companies that publish stock prediction source code

Tags: regression, predictive-models, arima, lstm

Now the best way to describe this is as follows:

For example Epic Games and Unity and Blender have the source code of their engines available for the public to read. Reading company code can be very educational.

In the same way are there Companies that distribute their predictions source code. For example: Barclays posting somewhere the source code for predicting the stock of AAPL using time series analysis. or Vanguard distributing the source code of predicting stock via regression

Has any of you found something like that??